# When a user returns to StackOverflow, suggest unanswered questions that the user can likely answer

Tags: feature-request

Feature Request:

> When a user returns to Stackoverflow,
>   and his/her answer history is well
>   known, suggest unanswered questions
>   that he/she might be able to answer.

For instance:

- If 'User A' has answered 50 C# questions, then he/she is well positioned to answer two C# questions that were asked 15 minutes ago.
- So call these out to 'User A' when he/she loads Stackoverflow.

Comment: Really?  So somebody who's answered 50 questions on ASP.NET MVC is well positioned to answer one on WPF, because they're both tagged `[c#]`?  This is incredibly naïve and annoying solution to a problem that's already been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new "interesting" sort on the front page of SO, I would probably be annoyed by this.  I've answered a bunch of c# questions, but there are *so many* c# questions, and only a small percentage are answerable by me.

It would be obnoxious to have to close a banner:

> Would you like to answer "I want
>   ecommerse web in c# send codez" or "What is the memory usage of the oracle c# driver library" right now?

Answer (score 6):

I'd say it's already [status-completed] - that's exactly what the New and Improved Homepage is supposed to do. See [this blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/), and the [Homepage tag on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homepage).